# PHP - How can my GET requests from my server obtain the same HTML code a browser would get?

Tags: php, html, http, get, request

I am working with PHP.

I'm trying to get the HTML code from DHL's tracking website, in order to parse it, given a certain tracking number and other parameters.

The response seems to send an empty HTML, but if I try the link in a browser, it works.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.dhl.com.mx/content/mx/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=DHL&AWB='.$shipment_number.'%0D%0A';
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
```

?>

Comment: How does `$html` look after the `file_get_contents` call? Is it FALSE or does it contain any data at all?

Comment: It contains an html file that tries to redirect me to the default page. I assume it comes from DHL servers whenever a request is not appropriately formed.

Comment: I see, then the `file_get_contents` request does what its supposed to, but the request is redirected. Not sure if you can set `file_get_contents` to follow redirects. Maybe try to use `curl`?

Comment: Some web services reject 'bot' user agents. Try using curl to spoof your user agent: http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof

Comment: i just checked the website it says the server is down for maintenance

Comment: Thanks! The curl method is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seem that the page Require User agent to access,they does not allow Bot

You can use **CURL** and set user agent as browser to get the page content